# MongoDB concatenate for dictionary key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to update a dictionary field in MongoDB. But I can't figure out a way to update nested dictionary with a variable as key.

Here is the schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    course: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

I am trying to update course so that every time a course name is added as a key in the following form, with course name stored in the variable `addName`

For example, if `addName = Intro to Computer Science`, the desired result would be

```
{
  "email" 12345@gmail.com,
  ...
  "course": {
     "Intro to Computer Science" {
        "syllabus": ""
      }

  }

}
```

However, I am not sure how to add a variable key to the dictionary. When I tried below, but I get the following syntax error

```
app.post("/api/add-course/", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const addName = req.body.addName;
  console.log(req.body)// assumes that User was registered in `./db.mjs`
  User.updateOne({"email": email}, {'$set': {'course.'+addName: {"syllabus": ""}}},
    ).then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({
        message: "success",
        course: user.course
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err),
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
  });
  console.log(user);
})
```

[image: syntax error]